# Google Geocoding API Returning Wrong Zip/City

Tags: api, zip, google-geocoding-api, geocode, postal-code

The address I am attempting to geocode is 1030 Pops Way, Bogart, GA 30622. Google seems to think this address is located in Watkinsville, GA 30677 and so returns Watkinsville and 30677. This is incorrect. Literally every other site listing addresses, including USPS, locates this address in Bogart 30622.

This is not the only instance of Google returning incorrect zip codes I have come across.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1030+pops+way+30622+bogart+ga&key=API-KEY

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Are you asking a programming question?  If this is a comment about the Google API then it will be off-topic here, and more appropriately posted to the relevant Google Group.

Comment: If every other site lists the correct address, why don't you use any of them instead? Say http://geocoder.ca/1030%20Pops%20Way,%20Bogart,%20GA%2030622

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a data issue on Google side.

Let's check the 'Pops Way, Bogart, GA 30622' request in Geocoder tool:

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DPops%2520Way%252C%2520Bogart%252C%2520GA%252030622

As you can see the result is a route with a postal code 30622 as shown in my screenshot

[image]

However if I click the building with number 1030 on this street the postal code changes to 30677

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D33.901296%252C-83.559744

as shown in the following screenshot

[image]

I can suggest reporting a wrong postal code in address to Google data team as explained in the documentation

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088

You can use this direct link

https://www.google.com/maps/@33.9017628,-83.5603702,18z/data=!10m1!1e1!12b1?rapsrc=apiv3

I hope this helps!